# "Q_WS_WIN undeclared" CMake error while building opencv2.4.13 on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04, failed-installation

I am getting the following error while installing opencv2.4.13 on Ubuntu16.04 system.

> char**)’:
>   /home/aashishsharma/Desktop/opencv-2.4.13/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.cxx:8:19: error: ‘Q_WS_WIN’ was not declared in this scope
>      return ((int*)(&Q_WS_WIN))[argc];

The entire log is present at - https://expirebox.com/download/fe00454e1088e949d122637b90fb1467.html

I have tried searching Google a lot, but couldn't find any helpful answer. Can anybody please help me out ?